# Could not override the previous click function in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, function, click, jquery-events

I have a script that shows and hides content using a jQuery click function. The problem arises when I introduced a close button which doesn't close when used. For some reason it could not override the previous class.

Here's the code

```js
var item = $('.list-item');

$(item).click(function() {

  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(item).not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).find('.exhibitor-content').addClass('block');
  $(item).not(this).find('.exhibitor-content').removeClass('block');

  var exhibitor_wrap = $(this).find('.exhibitor-wrap').height();
  var exhibitor_content = $(this).find('.exhibitor-content').height();
  var total_height = exhibitor_wrap + exhibitor_content + 28 + 56;

  $(this).find('.item-wrap').css({
    transition: 'height 350ms ease',
    height: total_height + 'px'
  });

  $(item).not(this).find('.item-wrap').css({
    transition: 'height 350ms ease',
    height: 'auto'
  });

});

$('.close-link').click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().removeClass('block');

});
```

```css
.future-exhibitor-links,
.exhibitor-list,
.list--unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.exhibitor-category {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.exhibitor-wrap {
  padding-top: 28px;
  padding-top: 1.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 1.75rem;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 0.625rem;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 0.625rem;
}

.exhibitor-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exhibitor-wrap:hover .exhibitor-category {
  color: #111;
}

.active .exhibitor-wrap {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.active .exhibitor-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.exhibitor-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  width: 3.125rem;
  height: 50px;
  height: 3.125rem;
  margin: 0 auto 7px;
  margin: 0 auto 0.4375rem;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.exhibitor-category-list {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 1.75rem;
  *zoom: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.exhibitor-category-list:before,
.exhibitor-category-list:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.exhibitor-category-list:after {
  clear: both;
}

.exhibitor-category-list>.list-item {
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.exhibitor-category-list>.list-item:before,
.exhibitor-category-list>.list-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.exhibitor-category-list>.list-item:after {
  clear: both;
}

.exhibitor-category-list>.list-item:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 568px) {
  .exhibitor-category-list>.list-item {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .exhibitor-category-list>.list-item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.exhibitor-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 28px 28px 0;
  padding: 1.75rem 28px 0;
  padding: 1.75rem 1.75rem 0;
  display: none;
}

.exhibitor-content.block {
  display: block;
}

.exhibitor-list {
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 1.75rem;
}

.exhibitor-list>.exhibitor-list-item {
  *zoom: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #959595;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0.875rem;
}

.exhibitor-list>.exhibitor-list-item:before,
.exhibitor-list>.exhibitor-list-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.exhibitor-list>.exhibitor-list-item:after {
  clear: both;
}

.exhibitor-list>.exhibitor-list-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-category-list">
  <li class="list-item active" id="bridal-attire">
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-bridal-attire"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Bridal Attire</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content block">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Bridal Attire</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 1</h3>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 2</h3>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="caterers">
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-caterers"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Caterers</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Caterers</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 3</h3>


            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="coordinators">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-coordinators"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Coordinators</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Coordinators</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 4</h3>

            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="florist-stylist">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-florist-stylist"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Florist &amp; Stylist</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Florist &amp; Stylist</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 5</h3>

            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="photography">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-photography"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Photography</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Photography</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 6</h3>

            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="videography">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-videography"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Videography</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Videography</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 7</h3>

            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your click handlers are conflicting. Use `event.stopPropagation()` on the `.close-link` click handler to keep that click from bubbling up and triggering a click on `item`

```js
var item = $('.list-item');

$(item).click(function() {

  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(item).not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).find('.exhibitor-content').addClass('block');
  $(item).not(this).find('.exhibitor-content').removeClass('block');

  var exhibitor_wrap = $(this).find('.exhibitor-wrap').height();
  var exhibitor_content = $(this).find('.exhibitor-content').height();
  var total_height = exhibitor_wrap + exhibitor_content + 28 + 56;

  $(this).find('.item-wrap').css({
    transition: 'height 350ms ease',
    height: total_height + 'px'
  });

  $(item).not(this).find('.item-wrap').css({
    transition: 'height 350ms ease',
    height: 'auto'
  });

});

$('.close-link').click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().removeClass('block');
  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

```css
.future-exhibitor-links,
.exhibitor-list,
.list--unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.exhibitor-category {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.exhibitor-wrap {
  padding-top: 28px;
  padding-top: 1.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 1.75rem;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 0.625rem;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 0.625rem;
}

.exhibitor-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exhibitor-wrap:hover .exhibitor-category {
  color: #111;
}

.active .exhibitor-wrap {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.active .exhibitor-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.exhibitor-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  width: 3.125rem;
  height: 50px;
  height: 3.125rem;
  margin: 0 auto 7px;
  margin: 0 auto 0.4375rem;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.exhibitor-category-list {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 1.75rem;
  *zoom: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.exhibitor-category-list:before,
.exhibitor-category-list:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.exhibitor-category-list:after {
  clear: both;
}

.exhibitor-category-list > .list-item {
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.exhibitor-category-list > .list-item:before,
.exhibitor-category-list > .list-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.exhibitor-category-list > .list-item:after {
  clear: both;
}

.exhibitor-category-list > .list-item:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 568px) {
  .exhibitor-category-list > .list-item {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .exhibitor-category-list > .list-item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.exhibitor-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 28px 28px 0;
  padding: 1.75rem 28px 0;
  padding: 1.75rem 1.75rem 0;
  display: none;
}

.exhibitor-content.block {
  display: block;
}

.exhibitor-list {
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 1.75rem;
}

.exhibitor-list > .exhibitor-list-item {
  *zoom: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #959595;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0.875rem;
}

.exhibitor-list > .exhibitor-list-item:before,
.exhibitor-list > .exhibitor-list-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.exhibitor-list > .exhibitor-list-item:after {
  clear: both;
}

.exhibitor-list > .exhibitor-list-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-category-list">
  <li class="list-item active" id="bridal-attire">
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-bridal-attire"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Bridal Attire</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content block">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Bridal Attire</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 1</h3>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 2</h3>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="caterers">
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-caterers"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Caterers</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Caterers</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 3</h3>


            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="coordinators">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-coordinators"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Coordinators</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Coordinators</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 4</h3>


            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="florist-stylist">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-florist-stylist"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Florist &amp; Stylist</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Florist &amp; Stylist</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 5</h3>


            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="photography">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-photography"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Photography</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Photography</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 6</h3>


            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" id="videography">
    <div class="item-wrap" style="transition: height 350ms ease; height: auto;">
      <div class="exhibitor-wrap">
        <i class="exhibitor-icon icon-videography"></i>
        <span class="exhibitor-category">Videography</span>
      </div>
      <div class="exhibitor-content">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--primary-dark-med">Videography</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--top">Close</a>
        <ul class="list--unstyled exhibitor-list">
          <li class="exhibitor-list-item">

            <div class="exhibitor-logo">logo here</div>
            <div class="exhibitor-details">

              <h3 class="exhibitor-detail--title">Exhibitor 7</h3>


            </div>
            <!-- // exhibitor-details -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="close-link close-link--bottom">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user1448731 you're welcome! Be sure to upvote if the post helps, and accept it as an answer if it solved your issue.